# Run length encoding not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I've been trying to create a program which reads a file with the text "iinnpputt" en writes it to another file with text "i2n2p2ut2". This works for me however it only writes "i2n2". Does anyone have any tips for me? I can't use libraries from python.

```
import sys

def vraagactie():
    print "Wilt u een bestand coderen of decoderen? Voer de eerste letter van de gewenste actie in."
    actie = raw_input()
    if actie == "c" :
        return
    if actie == "d" :
        return
    while actie != "c" and actie!= "d":
        print "Voer opnieuw de gewenste actie in"
        actie = raw_input()
        if actie == "c" or actie == "d":
            return actie

def vraagnaam():
    print "Wat is de naam van het bestand?"
    bestand = raw_input()
    return bestand

def vraagdoelnaam():
    print "Hoe wilt u de doelfile noemen?"
    doelfile = raw_input()
    return doelfile

def bestandlezen(a,b):
    try:
        invoer = open(a, "r")
        uitvoer = open(b, "w")
        return invoer, uitvoer
    except IOError:
        print "bestand niet te openen"
        sys.exit(1)

def coderen(invoer, uitvoer):
    string = ""
    kar = invoer.read()
    tel = 1
    lengte = len(kar)
    while len(string) < lengte:
        string += kar
        if string[0] == string[1]:
            tel += 1
            string = string[1::]
        if  string[0] != string [1]:
            uitvoer.write(string[0]+str(tel))
            tel = 1
            string = string[1::]
    return

def main():
    vraagactie()
    a = vraagnaam()
    b = vraagdoelnaam()
    invoer, uitvoer = bestandlezen(a,b)
    print coderen(invoer, uitvoer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I suggest your read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - this way you can see what is going on in program. Or learn how to use debuger.

Comment: What would be the expected output for a string like "unique"?

Comment: By logical deduction, the bug is most likely in your `coderen()` function, since that is where the output file is written. Since the output file is too short, it's probably because the `while` loop terminates too soon. Also note that the function effectively returns `None` because of the bare `return` at its end, so the `print coderen(invoer, uitvoer)` will always display that value.